# SQL Server 2008 - How to fill blank rows with data in other rows (either before or after blank rows)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am new to stackoverflow and I have a question that need your help. I have a table similar to below:

```
ID, Date,   Type
1   1/1/16  
1   2/1/16  
1   3/1/16  Apple
1   4/1/16  
1   5/1/16  
1   6/1/16  
2   1/1/16  Pear        
2   2/1/16          
2   3/1/16  Apple       
2   4/1/16          
2   5/1/16  Banana      
2   6/1/16          
3   1/1/16  
3   2/1/16  
3   3/1/16  
3   4/1/16  
3   5/1/16  
3   6/1/16  Pear
```

What I want to do is:

```
ID, Date,   Type
1   1/1/16  Apple
1   2/1/16  Apple
1   3/1/16  Apple
1   4/1/16  Apple
1   5/1/16  Apple
1   6/1/16  Apple
2   1/1/16  Pear        
2   2/1/16  Pear        
2   3/1/16  Apple       
2   4/1/16  Apple       
2   5/1/16  Banana      
2   6/1/16  Banana      
3   1/1/16  Pear
3   2/1/16  Pear
3   3/1/16  Pear
3   4/1/16  Pear
3   5/1/16  Pear
3   6/1/16  Pear
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this [Using APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
try this query:

```
SELECT t.id
, t.date
, t.type
, IsNull(t.[type], z.[type]) AS NewType
FROM t
OUTER APPLY 
 (SELECT x.[type] 
  FROM t AS x 
  WHERE x.date = 
    IsNull(
      (SELECT Max(p.date) AS pd FROM t AS p WHERE p.id = t.id AND p.date < t.date AND p.[type] Is Not Null) --Prev Not Null
    , (SELECT Min(n.date) AS nd FROM t AS n WHERE n.id = t.id AND n.date > t.date AND n.[type] Is Not Null) --Next Not Null
    ) AND x.id = t.id
  ) z
```